# Common base class in plug-in code

Tags: c++, c++11

The application defines 3 interfaces to be implemented in a plug-in. `Widget` is always the base.

```
// Application code...
class Widget {
    virtual void animate() = 0;
};

class BigWidget : public Widget {
};

class SmallWidget : public Widget {
};
```

Every interface implementation is derived from `NiceWidget` which provides some plug-in internal common information.

```
// Plug-in code...
class NiceWidget {
    // nice::Thing is only known in plug-in code.
    nice::Thing thing();
};

class NiceBigWidget : public NiceWidget, public BigWidget {
    void animate() override;
};

class NiceSmallWidget : public NiceWidget, public SmallWidget {
    void animate() override;
};
```

`func` is called from application code. `wid` is known to be implemented by this plugin. Thus wid is also a `NiceWidget`. The goal of `func` is to call the `thing` method of it.

```
// Plugin-in code...
void func(Widget* wid) {
    // wid is either NiceBigWidget or NiceSmallWidget.
    auto castedBig = dynamic_cast<NiceBigWidget*>(wid);
    if (castedBig) {
        castedBig->thing().foo();
        return;
    }

    auto castedSmall = dynamic_cast<NiceSmallWidget*>(wid);
    if (castedSmall) {
        castedSmall->thing().foo();
        return;
    }

    assert(false);
}
```

But trying to cast `wid` to every `Nice*` can become very awful with increasing hierarchy size. Are there better solutions out there?

Comment: Why don't you simply cast to `NiceWidget`?

Comment: Why func gets `Widget`, not `NiceWidget` if you know it's `NiceWidget`

Comment: Because func is called from application code. NiceWidget is unknown in application code.

Comment: @hpohl, anyway app.code should somehow know, that if it isn't `NiceWidget`, it shouldn't call it, shouldn't it?

Comment: Right you are. Still it does not know NiceWidget. The common base class of another plugin could be `BadPlugin`.

Comment: @hpohl And how does `func` take that scenario with `BadPlugin` into account? The solution here seems clear to me: if there is a common interface to be used by application code *make a common interface to be used by application code*. Anything else amounts to self-inflicted problems.

Comment: The assertion in `func` will fail or an exception will be thrown (in the case it depends on user input). `NiceWidget::thing` is plug-in internal and has no place in the common interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: if you know that `wid` will always be a `NiceWidget*`, why not say so in `func()`? And you would not need a cast at all:

```
void func(NiceWidget* wid)
{
  wid->thing().foo();  // Done
}
```

Even if you can't change the function signature for whatever reason, you would only need one cast:

```
void func(Widget* wid)
{
  NiceWidget* casted = dynamic_cast<NiceWidget*>(wid);
  if (casted)
    casted->thing().foo();
  else
    throw std::exception(); // Well, throw the right exception
}
```

You can `assert()` instead of throwing an exception, of course, if you think it is better for your purposes.

In any case, you just need a pointer to the class that defines the functions you need to use (in this case, `thing()`), not to the most derived classes. If you will override the function in derived classes, make it virtual and you are done anyway.

Comment: I guess it may be required turning NiceWidget a virtual class (which it's not shown it's), because without that, that dynamic_cast may fail.

Comment: @chico Right, at least it would need a virtual destructor. Same goes for `Widget`, anyway.

Comment: Did not know about that ability of dynamic_cast. Great solution for virtual classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you know, that every `NiceWidget` is `Widget`, you should consider extending `NiceWidget` from `Widget`.

```
class Widget {
    virtual void animate() = 0;
};

class BigWidget : public Widget {
};

class SmallWidget : public Widget {
};

class NiceWidget : Widget{
    // nice::Thing is only known in plug-in code.
    nice::Thing thing();
};


class NiceBigWidget : public NiceWidget, public BigWidget {
    void animate() override;
};

class NiceSmallWidget : public NiceWidget, public SmallWidget {
    void animate() override;
};
```

There will be another problem called [The diamond problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem), and it may be solved using virtual extending

After that it's should be OK to `dynamic_cast` from `Widget` to `NiceWidget`